# AngularJs app optimization for mobile and all devices, using Bootstrap: Not displaying as desired

Tags: android, html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am creating a little `AngularJs` app that I want to optimize for all platforms and devices. I am using `Bootstrap` as my main styling method. This is a first for me, so I would appreciate your patience :D.

I have a basic skeleton of the app, but I have found that browsing the app on my mobile device, it does not display the way I imagined and desire.

This is a screenshot taken on my phone (Android):

[image]

I would like it to display like this:

[image]

Here is my `index.html` code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>IMPI Technical Services</title>

    <!-- Style sheets -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/app.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/toastr.css" />

    <!-- favicons -->
    <!-- For IE 9 and below. ICO should be 32x32 pixels in size -->
    <!--[if IE]><link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicon/favicon.ico"><![endif]-->
    <!-- Touch Icons - iOS and Android 2.1+ 180x180 pixels in size. -->
    <link rel="images/favicon/apple-icon-180x180.png" href="images/favicon/apple-icon-180x180.png">

    <!-- Firefox, Chrome, Safari, IE 11+ and Opera. 196x196 pixels in size. -->
    <link rel="icon" href="images/favicon/android-icon-192x192.png">

</head>

<body ng-app="impi-app">

    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
        <div class="container">
            <a class="navbar-brand" ui-sref="home">IMPI Techincal Services</a>
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button"
                        class="navbar-toggle"
                        data-toggle="collapse"
                        data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><a ui-sref="about">About</a></li>
                    <li><a ui-sref="products">Products</a></li>
                    <li><a ui-sref="contact">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>

    <div class="container">
        <div ui-view></div>
    </div>

    <!-- Footer -->
    <div class="container" id="copyright">
        <div>
            <footer>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-xs-12">
                        <p>Copyright &copy; Impi Technical Service 2017</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </footer>
        </div>
    </div>

    ...

</body>

</html>
```

Here is the home view code:

```
    <!-- Page Content -->
<div class="container">
    <!-- Jumbotron Header -->
    <header class="jumbotron hero-spacer">
        <h2>A Warm Welcome!</h2>
        <p>
            This is the new home of IMPI Technical Services. We specialise in the delivery of specialised - customer focused - mining and construction
            industry products and services.
        </p>
        <br />
        <p>
            Our site is currently under development, and we are looking forward to bringing you a feature rich, customer experience. For ANY queries, you are more
            that welcome to contact us directly, or to fill in our contact form!
        </p>
        <p>
            <a class="btn btn-primary btn-large" ui-sref="contact">Contact Form</a>
        </p>
    </header>
    <hr>
    <!-- Title -->
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <h3>We Are Proud Suppliers Of:</h3>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /.row -->
    <!-- Page Features -->
    <div class="row text-center">
        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 hero-feature">
            <div class="thumbnail">
                <img src="../images/supplier_images/rockmore.jpg" alt="Rockmore International">
                <div class="caption">
                    <h3>Rockmore International</h3>
                    <p>Rockmore International is one of the worlds leading manufacturers of top quality percussive rock drilling tools.</p>
                    <p>
                        <a href="http://rockmore-intl.com" target="_blank" class="btn btn-primary">Visit Site</a>
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 hero-feature">
            <div class="thumbnail">
                <img src="../images/supplier_images/Montbert.jpg" alt="Montabert Hydraulic Drifters">
                <div class="caption">
                    <h3>Montabert Hydraulic Drifters</h3>
                    <p>
                        Montabert was founded in 1921 by Joannes Montabert as Montabert S.A, a manufacturer of pneumatic equipment that would
                        introduce the first hydraulic concrete breakers and drifters. In 1935, through the initiative of Suzanne Montabert,
                        the company expanded its product line and added the Sullivan Ikine line of products under license.
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        <a href="http://montabertsa.co.za" target="_blank" class="btn btn-primary">Visit Site</a>
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6  col-xs-12 hero-feature">
            <div class="thumbnail">
                <img src="../images/supplier_images/vula-drilling.png" alt="Vulla Drilling">
                <div class="caption">
                    <h3>Vula Drilling (Pty) Ltd</h3>
                    <p>
                        VULA Drilling (Pty) Ltd. is the Original Equipment Supplier (OES) of the patented VULA range of hard-rock drill bits.
                        This new range of drill bits have been specifically designed and developed with the use of ultra modern
                        Computer-Aided-Design-and-Manufacturing (CAD/CAM) Software to improve penetration rates and increase flushing of the drill bit,
                        resulting in an increase in productivity and meters drilled.
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        <a href="http://vuladrilling.co.za" target="_blank" class="btn btn-primary">Visit Site</a>
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 hero-feature">
            <div class="thumbnail">
                <img src="../images/supplier_images/powerbit.png" alt="Powerbit Rocktools">
                <div class="caption">
                    <h3>Powerbit Rocktools</h3>
                    <p>
                        Powerbit Rocktools has been in operation since 1996. They are a South African based company, with clients all over Africa.
                        Their factories are located in Taiwan and China.
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        <a href="http://powerbit.co.za" target="_blank" class="btn btn-primary">Visit Site</a>
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /.row -->
    <hr>>
</div>
```

Any pointers on what I am missing or doing wrong?

This is the site address if you'd like to view it on your own mobile device to test the display: www.impitechservices.co.za

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a few meta tags in the head tag.

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

These tags are required to enable proper rendering of a page.

Comment: Thank you so much! You rock! :D